# Combine two regex in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, parsing, select-string

This is the data I am trying to parse:

10.186.128.0/20  172.17.128.161                         0 65000 8788

10.186.128.0/20  172.17.128.161                         0 65000 878

10.186.128.0/20  172.17.128.161                         0 65000 87

Ideally the output should match the IP address from the beginning of the line and also last 2 or 3 or 4 digits.
Example desired output:

10.186.128.0/20 8788

10.186.128.0/20 878

10.186.128.0/20 87

I have regex that will match the IP address `"10\.\d*\.\d*\.\d*\/\d\d"`

And then I have second regex that will match the last 2 or 3 or 4 digits `" \d{4}$| \d{3}$| \d{2}$"`

Question is how to combine those two regex expressions in PowerShell to achieve desired result?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `$s -replace '^(10(?:\.\d+){3}/\d+)\s.*\s(\d+)$', '$1 $2'`? Or do you mean the text contains lines that need to be extracted first?

Comment: If you are trying to match IP adresse, there will never be more than 3 digit between dots, and never less than 1. You should change your regex to `10\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\/\d{2}`

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I modified my IP matching regex. However how to achieve the desired outcome of getting the IP and also the last 2 or 3 or 4 digits in the string?

Comment: I've created a [regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/imc77v/1) for you to test more cases, basically, i've added a space an a match for 2 to 4 digits.

Comment: `Select-String '(?m)^(10(?:\.\d+){3}/\d+)\s.*\s(\d+)\r?$'
 -input $txt -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.matches} | Foreach {$_.groups[1].value +
" " + $_.groups[2].value}`? Note the `$txt` here is a multiline string input. It outputs expected result in PS 6.1.3

Comment: Try also `Get-Content $filepath | Select-String '^(10(?:\.\d+){3}/\d+)\s.*\s(\d+)$' -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {$_.Matches} | Foreach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value + " " + $_.Groups[2].Value}`

Comment: last comment from Wiktor Stribiżew worked exactly the way I needed. Many thanks. Feel free to post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
Get-Content $filepath | Select-String '^(10(?:\.\d+){3}/\d+)\s.*\s(\d+)$' -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {$_.Matches} | Foreach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value + " " + $_.Groups[2].Value}
```

The `^(10(?:\.\d+){3}/\d+)\s.*\s(\d+)$` regex - see [its online demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%2810%28%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B%29%7B3%7D%2F%5Cd%2B%29%5Cs.*%5Cs%28%5Cd%2B%29%5Cr%3F%24&i=10.186.128.0%2F20%20%20172.17.128.161%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%200%2065000%208788%0D%0A10.186.128.0%2F20%20%20172.17.128.161%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%200%2065000%20878%0D%0A10.186.128.0%2F20%20%20172.17.128.161%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%200%2065000%2087&o=m) - matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(10(?:\.\d+){3}/\d+)` - Group 1: `10`, then three repetitions of a dot and any 1+ digits and then `/` and 1+ digits
- `\s.*\s`  - a whitespace, any 0+ chars other than newline as many as possible and a whitespace
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: 1+ digits
- `$`  - end of string.

So,

- `Get-Content $filepath` reads the file
- `Select-String '^(10(?:\.\d+){3}/\d+)\s.*\s(\d+)$' -AllMatches` gets all matches from the file that it gets by  reading the file line by line
- `Foreach-Object {$_.Matches}` grabs all matches one by one
- `Foreach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value + " " + $_.Groups[2].Value}` concats Group 1 and 2 values.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `-split` seems much simpler if all of your data is consistently in the posted format.

```
Get-Content -Path file.txt |
    Foreach-Object { [string]($_ -split ' ')[0,-1] }
```

**Explanation:**

`-split` uses regex matching to split a string into an array of strings. Here the string is split based on a single space. `[0,-1]` selects the first (index 0) and last (index -1) elements of the array.

`[string]` casts the two array elements as a string. Since PowerShell automatically joins two items with a space when they are cast as a string, this is just merely a shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

If a quick way to modify the string is all that's needed
a simple replace with one of these two regex :

```
$string -replace '(?<=\b10\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}/\d{2}).*(?=[ \t]\d{1,4}\b)', ''
```

or

```
$string -replace '(?m)(?<=^[ \t]*10\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}/\d{2}).*(?=[ \t]\d{1,4}[ \t]*$)', ''
```

Comment: This solution would effectively remove the part that I am looking to retrieve. The solution provided by Wiktor Stribiżew works perfectly fine so it should be marked as the right answer IMHO.

Comment: @JozefTrubac - The resulting string is the IP address from the beginning of the line and also last 2 or 3 or 4 digits.

Comment: @JozefTrubac - I never read or look at other answers as I consider myself an expert. See Possible [duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390629/should-stack-overflow-remove-the-regex-tag).